# QR barcode carriage return

Tags: qr-code

How do you encode a carriage return in a QR barcode (so if I scan it with my android, for instance it will come up)

```
A
B
C
```

I have tried `A~d013B~d013C` etc. but it always shows the escape characters (among other ways I have found, none of which seem to work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply encode it by putting the correct byte sequence into the QR code. Assuming you're using the default ISO-8859-1 encoding, that's just the single byte 0x0D.

I imagine you know this so perhaps you are really asking how to specify this character/byte to some particular encoder? I can tell you that http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/ will easily let you do this in its "Text" mode as it gives you textarea to type into, where you can simply type a carriage return.

It in turn just generates a URL to the chart server:

http://zxing.org/w/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=a%0Ab%0Ac

Here it's actually inserted line feeds (is that what you mean?), but you could edit the URL above to insert %0D for a carriage return as you like.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it's still one of the top results in Google and I'd like to add for future searches the JavaScript encoding.

Inside JavaScript you can do this using `\u000A` to insert LF or `\u000D` to insert CR. For example:

```
const qrData = 'Line 1 ' +
    '\u000A Line 2' +
    '\u000A Line 3' +
    '\u000A Line 4';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<:CR>` to `%0D` and it will line break for you as you'd like.