# QR Code enter key C#

Tags: c#, qr-code

I`m trying to develop a program which generate qr code automatically. How can I insert "enter key" in my code?

### Thank you!

Here is how i generate QR code:

```
string text_to_encode = "it"  + "\t " + "works" + "Enter here" + "done";
QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
encoder.QRCodeScale = 5;
encoder.QRCodeVersion = 2;
Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(text_to_encode);

img.Save(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\qrcodes\\" + "qrcode" + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I think he's talking about the newline character. Did you try "\n"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QR barcode carriage return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422042/qr-barcode-carriage-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line feed (enter key) can be encoded as `"\r\n"` or just a `"\n"` or you can use `System.Environment.NewLine`:

```
string text_to_encode = "it"  + "\t " + "works" + "\r\n" + "done";


string text_to_encode = "it"  + "\t " + "works" + System.Environment.NewLine + "done";
```